# Frequency Analysis on OS X using veclib

Tags: macos, cocoa, fft, foundation, accelerate-framework

I am looking for any examples of frequency analysis on os x. I understand that I should calculate the FFT of a sample of audio. I have code examples from apple's website for performing ffts:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/AccelerateFrameworkData/_index.html

However, I am looking for any examples that explain how the real and imaginary components translate into frequency and amplitude components. I have a very simple tone which I am looking to calculate the frequency of.

Answer (score 2):

After the FFT you need to take the *magnitude* of each complex output bin:

```
magnitude = sqrt(re[i]*re[i] + im[i]*im[i]);
```

The *frequency* is related to the bin index, i:

```
freq = i * Fs / N;
```

where Fs = sample rate (Hz), N = FFT size.

If you're just looking for a single tone, then find the bin index with the largest magnitude, then convert this index to a frequency using the above formula. Note that you only need to check bin indices from 1 to N/2-1.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. As for the magnitude, is this on a scale of 0 to 1? Or would it be an expression of power or pressure like a decibel?

Comment: The scale of magnitude is not too important in this context, since all you are looking for is a peak. In general though for an input signal of magnitude 1 the FFT bin magnitude will have a value of N, where N is the size of the FFT. When you care about the actual value you typically scale by 1/N to compensate for this. Note also that you should look into applying a window function prior to the FFT.

Answer (score 2):

The center frequency for each FFT bin has been answered by Paul R.  However note that the precise frequency in the audio you wish to analyze may not be at the center of any FFT bin.  So what you may be looking for instead might be a frequency estimation algorithm using an FFT, or, for audio containing music or speech, a pitch detection/estimation method, which is different from frequency estimation.